# raise a Matrix to the power in c

Tags: c, math, matrix, exponent

Trying to raise a matrix to the power of p, but I dont find the mistake. Can anyone help and explain the problem? I just got started in programming in C so thank you very much for your help. The user should enter a matrix and it should be raised to the power of p.

```
int main() {
    int n, p;
    printf("Number of Rows/Colums of square matrix: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("to the power of: ");
    scanf("%d", &p);
    int m[n][n];
    int r[n][n];

    printf("Elements\n");
    for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
            printf("[%d][%d] = ", b + 1, d + 1);
            scanf("%d", &m[b][d]);
        }
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    sum += m[b][k] * m[k][d];
                }
                r[b][d] = sum;
                sum = 1;
            }
        }

        for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
                m[b][d] = r[b][d];
                r[b][d] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("RESULT:-\n");

    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
            printf("%d   ", m[c][d]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show a simple example of input and expect vs. actual output.

Comment: Why is `sum` set to 1 after the inner loop? Shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: Set `sum` to zero before the loop on `k`, not the loop on `i`. (Then the later assignment `sum = 1;` becomes irrelevant. It should be removed.)

Comment: There's nothing like an O(N4) algorithm! There are more efficient ways: going the eigenvalue / eigenvector root is probably the best.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Not appropriate for this level of learning. The goal here is not to raise a matrix to a power. The goal here is to learn elementary C. You do not tell hikers they could get to their destinations faster with a car.

Comment: @EricPostpischil or just replace `sum = 1` with `sum = 0`, same effect except for an extra assignment at the end.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It doesn't hurt to acquaint beginners with the notion of computational efficiency. Furthermore, given the topic selection, there is a nontrivial chance that this is in a class where the target audience includes math or engineering majors. It couldn't hurt to inform such students that there are better algorithms.

Comment: Besides the `sum` thing (should be reset to `0`) and that setting `r` to zeros does not really make a difference here, I think your algorithm would compute `m` to the power of 2ⁿ? Since on each iteration you have something like `m = m * m`.

Comment: @Beginner Others have made comments about fixing some specific problems. Here is some general advice about how to go about writing programs, which I think will help you with this program and others: try to separate the problem into self-contained parts and then work on the parts one at a time. In this case, maybe the parts are: input a matrix, output a matrix, multiply matrices, raise a matrix to a power.

Comment: don't remove the code from the question like that

Answer (score 2):

Your program logic is wrong at several levels.

This is your corrected program. There is still room for improvement (breaking the code down into functions, using better variable naming, using a more efficient algorithm than brute matrix multiplication, treating correctly the case where p is 0), but I tried to stick as much as possible to the  original wrong implementation.

This is the approach: we have three matrixes: `r` the result, `m` the matrix provided by user, and `temp` a temporary matrix.

1. Initially we copy `m` into `r`, this is the result for `p = 1`
2. We repeat steps 3 and 4 `p - 1` times
3. We multiply `r` and `m` and put the result into `temp`
4. We copy `temp` into  `r`
5. Now `r` contains the `m` elevated to the power of `p`.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n, p;
  printf("Numer of Rows/Colums of sq matrix: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("to the power of: ");
  scanf("%d", &p);
  int m[n][n];
  int r[n][n];
  int temp[n][n];

  printf("Elements\n");
  for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {
    for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
      printf("[%d][%d] = ", b + 1, d + 1);
      scanf("%d", &m[b][d]);
    }
  }

  // r = m
  // temp = m
  for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {
    for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
      r[b][d]   = m[b][d];
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < p - 1; i++)  // p - 1 because for p = 1, r already 
  {                                // contains the result
    int sum = 0;

    // temp = r * m
    for (int b = 0; b < n; b++)
    {
      for (int d = 0; d < n; d++)
      {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
          sum += m[b][k] * r[k][d];
        }
        temp[b][d] = sum;
        sum = 0;
      }
    }

    // r = temp
    for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {
      for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
        r[b][d] = temp[b][d];
      }
    }
  }

  printf("RESULT:\n");

  for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
  {
    for (int d = 0; d < n; d++)
    {
      printf("%d   ", r[c][d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AntoineMathys good point for p = 0, answer edited. But the `temp` is needed here. If you can provide a solution without `temp` post an answer, I'd be interested.

Comment: As I noted [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52556865/raise-a-matrix-to-the-power-in-c#comment92056299_52558019), I'd declare `int sum = 0;` just before the innermost loop, and then there's no need to reset it after the loop.  It limits the scope of the variable and avoids zeroing the sum after the fact.  It's generally better to initialize before a loop than to reset after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have various logical problems in your code.

The outer loop is wrong since you loop one time less the power quantity.

Secondly you need a buffer matrix the way you wrote your code.

Another problem is that when you multiply the row/column values, you always use the original matrix. This is logically wrong, you need to multiply the matrix computed up the current power by the original matrix.

I also don't understand why you reset the `sum` variable to 1 and not 0.

Something like this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int n, p;
printf("Numer of Rows/Colums of sq matrix: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("to the power of: ");
scanf("%d", &p);
int m[n][n];
int r[n][n];
int tmp[n][n];

printf("Elements\n");
for ( int b = 0 ; b < n ; b++ ) {
    for ( int d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ ) {
        printf("[%d][%d] = ", b+1, d+1);
        scanf("%d", &m[b][d]);
        r[b][d] = m[b][d];
    }
}

int sum = 0;
//you loop 1 time less of the power
for (int i = 0; i < p - 1; i++)
{
    for ( int b = 0 ; b < n ; b++ )
    {
        for (int d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
        {
            for (int k = 0 ; k < n ; k++ )
            {
                sum += r[b][k]*m[k][d];
            }
            tmp[b][d] = sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }

    for ( int b = 0 ; b < n ; b++ ) {
        for ( int d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ ) {
            //m[b][d] = r[b][d];
            r[b][d] = tmp[b][d];
        }
    }
}

printf("RESULT:-\n");

for (int c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
{
    for (int d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
    {
        printf("%d   ", r[c][d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

I would just point out that this solution probably does not work with p < 1

Comment: I'd declare `int sum = 0;` just before the innermost loop, and then there's no need to reset it after the loop.  It limits the scope of the variable and avoids zeroing the sum after the fact.  It's generally better to initialize before a loop than to reset after the loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I totally agree with you, I didn't think about it when while modifying the code.

Comment: I would also like to point out that a possible optimization is to nest the powers and multiply these instead of multiplying iteratively. For example A^8 = ((A^2)^2)^2, so instead of performing 7 multiplications you would only perform 3. But the management of these cases makes the code more complicated and requires to find the exponent's GCD (Greatest Common Divisor).

Comment: I agree that the algorithm could be improved at the macro level — a matrix multiplication function would be my first step, and then using roughly the technique you outline for large powers (it has to be refined a bit to get A^7 = A^4.A^2.A^1 but is on the right track).

Comment: Yep, also noticeable that even though matrix multiplication is usually not commutative, this case falls in the matrix commutative multiplication case. This means that the operands order does not change the result in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you decompose this complex problem into smaller problems.

Create smaller functions, test them to make sure they're working, and then take the next step calling those until you have the full set.

You need to start with a matrix: `a[m][n]`.  Should the values it holds be integers, floats, doubles?  Make sure you can create a matrix of different sizes.  What should your restrictions on rows and columns be?

Begin with methods to read and write your matrix.

Next is a method to multiple two matricies together: `c[m][n] = a[m][k]*b[k][n]`.  The number of columns in `a` has match the number of rows in `b` or you can't multiply.

Raising a matrix to an integer power `p > 1` means multiplying the starting matrix by itself `p` times.  Can you see that one requirement is that the starting matrix has to be square?  (# rows == # columns)  If that's not true, you can't raise to an integer power.

You'll need a loop to raise to a power p times.   You will call your matrix multiplication method `c = mult(a, b)` each time through the loop.  Each pass through will take the output from the previous call and make it the first matrix in the call:  `c = mult(c, b)`.

If you attack the problem this way you should be able to solve it.  Be sure to test each step carefully before you move on.

This is called decomposition.  It's bedrock for problem solving in general and computer science in particular.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- you should use a temporary matrix `t` to compute the result of `r * m` and copy that to `r` before the next step.
- `sum` should be re-initialized to `0`, or better, initialized to `0` before the `k` loop.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, p;
    printf("Number of Rows/Colums of square matrix: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0)
        return 1;
    printf("to the power of: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &p) != 1 || p < 0)
        return 1;

    int m[n][n];
    int r[n][n];
    int t[n][n];

    printf("Elements\n");
    for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
            printf("[%d][%d] = ", b + 1, d + 1);
            if (scanf("%d", &m[b][d]) != 1)
                return 1;
            r[b][d] = b == d; // initialize r to identity matrix
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    sum += r[b][k] * m[k][d];
                }
                t[b][d] = sum;
            }
        }
        for (int b = 0; b < n; b++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
                r[b][d] = t[b][d];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("RESULT:\n");
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
            printf("%3d ", r[c][d]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- The above code works for positive powers, including `0` which produces the identity matrix.
- Note however that this method is inefficient for large powers and `int` is likely to overflow for large powers anyway.